# Hide entire row after button click

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I am using ion-cards with a ngFor-loop. All cards include a row with feedback buttons. I would like to hide the entire row if a button for this card was clicked. My approach do not work. Thank you for your hints.

**Error**

```
No value accessor for form control with unspecific name attribute
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-card class="card card-ios" *ngFor="let card of cardArray; let i = index">
 ...
<ion-row [(ngModel)]="feedBackButtons[$i + 1]">
    <ion-col>
      <button class="thumbButtons" ion-button icon-start clear small (click)="tileViewThumbUp(i, card.category, card.coveredText)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
            <div>{{"Helpful" | translate }}</div>
          </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button class="thumbButtons" ion-button icon-start clear small (click)="tileViewThumbDown(i, card.category, card.coveredText)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-thumbs-down"></ion-icon>
            <div>{{"NotHelpful" | translate }}</div>
          </button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
...
```

**JS**

```
feedBackButtons: boolean = true;

...

tileViewThumbUp(index, category, coveredText) {
   this.feedBackButtons[index] = false;
}
tileViewThumbDown(index, category, coveredText) {
   this.feedBackButtons[index] = false;
}
```

Comment: looks like the fix is right there in the error: add a `name` attribute to your form controls

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved by this approach:

```
    <ion-row [hidden]="card.hideFeedback">
    <ion-col>
      <button class="thumbButtons" ion-button icon-start clear small (click)="card.hideFeedback = !card.hideFeedback;tileViewThumbUp(card.category, card.coveredText)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
            <div>{{"Helpful" | translate }}</div>
          </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button class="thumbButtons" ion-button icon-start clear small (click)="card.hideFeedback = !card.hideFeedback;tileViewThumbDown(card.category, card.coveredText)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-thumbs-down"></ion-icon>
            <div>{{"NotHelpful" | translate }}</div>
          </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```